# xml XmlPullParser

Tags: java, android, xml

Иду от простого, начинаю с XML PullParser.

Вопрос:
у меня XML такого вида:

XML

```
<data>
    <e>
        <message>
        </message>
    </e>
    <from>
        <id>
            487
        </id>
      </to>
    <routes>
        <item>
            <index>0</index>
            <from_date_part>from_night</from_date_part>
            <to_date_part>to_morning</to_date_part>
            <info/>           
        </item>
        <item>
            <index>0</index>
            <from_date_part>from_night</from_date_part>
            <to_date_part>to_morning</to_date_part>
            <info/>           
        </item>

         <item>
            <index>0</index>
            <from_date_part>from_night</from_date_part>
            <to_date_part>to_morning</to_date_part>
            <info/>           
        </item>
</routes>
</data>
```

Но мне нужна выборка только тега `</routes>` и там читать все `<item>` их может быть несколько.

делаю лист вью но он почему то? читает только последний `<item>`, почему так?

```
public class XmlPullParserHandler {
private List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
private Employee employee;
private String text;

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public List<Employee> parse(InputStream is) {
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();

       // parser.setInput(is, null); //было так
        parser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");
        // parser.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("routes")) {
                        // create a new instance of employee
                        employee = new Employee();
                    }

            }

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                text = parser.getText();
            }

            if (eventType ==  XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    // add employee object to list
                    employees.add(employee);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("index")) {
                    employee.setId(text);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("from_date_part")) {
                    employee.setName(text);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("to_date_part")) {
                    employee.setSalary(text);
                }
            }

            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}

    return employees;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
employee = new Employee();
```

добавьте

```
employees.add(employee);
```

должно получится так

```
if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("routes")) {
    // create a new instance of employee
    employee = new Employee();
    employees.add(employee);
}
```

и, чтобы не путаться, я бы объявил `employee` как локальную переменную.